# Geany Class member Sidebar

Tags: geany

In eclipse, when I open a file there is a sidebar which shows me all of the methods and global variables in the file. Is there a way I can get similar functionality for Geany?

Answer (score 1):

Geany shows this one the sidebar as well, it's on a tab labeled "Symbols".
You can see an example here: 
[image: Symbol List]

What I'm not sure about is which languages it supports. It has worked with every language I have tried so far (JavaScript, Java, C, Python, C++) but it doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Symbols-sidebar by selecting "Preferences" in the Edit-menu. In the "Interface" tab, check "Show symbol list".