# Missing class-member in geany's symbols sidebar

Tags: python, geany, class-members

I'm coding in python with Geany (v1.28 on LMDE2).

I set my Geany's conf with [standard Python filetype](https://wiki.geany.org/config/python).

Sidebar shows: classes & imports symbols, but no attributes.

[image]

When code is outside a class, variables and functions appears too.

With other languages (java?) some *[members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043408/6709630)* appears.

[Geany's manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/) didn't mention something about configuring te *symbol sidebar*, it looks like it use the *filetype* for that. Did I miss some config tip or this is normal behavior?

Comment: That's the level of detail that I'm used to seeing.  Is that a problem?  It's enough to find my way around a large file.

Comment: OK, maybe I must submit a feature request to the project. I liked to see here my _class attributes_, like in my screenshot: `Map._line_nb`,  `Map._colunm_nb`, `Map._robot_position`, etc.

Comment: You want it to scan all methods for `self.foo=` assignments?  Those aren't class attributes.  Those are instance attributes, assigned when an instance is created, not when the class is imported.

Comment: Hum… maybe I'm confusing… `self.attribute` is an **instance attribute** and `MyClass.attribute` is a **class attribute**, no? Then I just wish having my attributes names avaiable in the sidebar to find it rapidly.

Comment: It does identify class attributes.  It does not track assignments within functions or methods (not even the __init__).